# How do you say “geek”/“IT guy” in German?

Tags: usage, single-word-request

How do you call the kind of people who either work in IT or spend a lot of time with this kind of stuff?

The only word I’ve found is *Streber* but it seems to have a negative connotation (like *nerd*).

Comment: The German word for *geek* is *Geek*. Or *Computerfreak*, if you must. But really, go with *Geek*. And hands off *Streber*, that has nothing to do with anything here. Not the same ballpark, not the same game, not the same sport.

Comment: Younger people definitely use nerd and geek.

Comment: _Techniker_, _Informatiker_ ‘computer scientist’, _Computer-/IT-Leute/-Menschen_ or _ITler_ where the capital letters can be spelt German /i.te/ or English /ai.ti/, but are never pronounced /it/. _Bildschirmgebräunte_.

Comment: Unless you want to sound like a language learner or tourist, use the English terms in Germany. Except you want to talk _about_ Germans. All but elderly people use Geek & Nerd for geeks & nerds. Also IT-Experte. Streber & Freak are used in a rather derogatory manner. IT-Freak / Computer-Freak is someone who is too obsessed and spends too much time with it. Maybe also -Fuzzi, -Heini, both with negative connotations similar to a Hampelmann who may overcomplicate things.

Comment: In Danish the words like "computer" and "nerd" that we borrow from English, tend to have a much more narrow meaning than originally in English. Example:  "Mail" now mean an e-mail and only that.  Interesting though that "Streber" in German has very close to the same meaning as the word "Stræber" in Danish - along with unfortunate connotations and all.

Comment: A Computer-Profi is someone, that makes a living from computers. A Computer-Spezi often has a undercurrent of "a very special person" as in "strange" (in Switzerland at least). EDVler and ITler are people that work in EDV, that is IT. The special meaning of geek is lost in all translations, as a geek is somebody living and breathing IT and being very good in it. Sadly enough, even Profi for professional does not imply that somebody is good in his job. But since IT is largely English based even in Germany, Geek, Nerd, Freak, Hacker carry the same meaning as in Englsih and are widely used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately another area where little understood English terms have taken the cake.

- **Geek**: originally a person biting heads off of small animals

  - The subspecies **technology geek** is what is known in German as *der Geek*
  - Indirectly related to *jeck* (often heard during carnival season) - fool, jester ...
  - Reminds one of *der Elf/die Elfe* while the German word *Alb/Alp* already existed by the time
- **Freak**: directly translatable to German as *Missgeburt* (*monstrosity*), however often used especially by young people with a positive connotation.
- **Nerd**: allegedly the pronunciation you end up with when you reverse “drunk”, but origins unclear

Some hold there is an inherent difference between geek and nerd, to which geek/nerd website XKCD responded with this [Venn diagram](https://xkcd.com/747/).

If you were looking for a genuinely German word you’d be out of luck I reckon, because all alternatives contain word parts that are not originally of Germanic heritage.

Possibilities I would consider:

- **Computer-Profi** kind of implies a professional relation to the interest, though

  - If you’d substitute *Computer* for the the German word *Rechner* above it would sound totally weird
- **Computer-Spezi** (*Spezi* from *Spezialist*) can obviously also be assigned to people that otherwise don’t qualify as technology geek/nerd

  - However: as pointed out in comments, *Spezi* is also used in Southern Germany (particularly Bavarian regions) and Austria for a *friend*.
- **EDV-Spezi**
- **EDVler** (*EDV* = *Elektronische Datenverarbeitung*; roughly: electronic data processing) from my experience would be less used than (but equally legit as) **ITler** (with the acronym pronounced as in English … Ei-tie-ler)
- **Computerfreak**: is no less pejorative than *Streber* in my book.

Except for *Computerfreak* these are relatively neutral (i.e. not pejorative).

A good alternative for *Spezi* above would also be *Guru* (of the same meaning it carries in English), i.e. **Computerguru**, **IT-Guru** and … somewhat awkward sounding … EDV-Guru. *Guru* also came up in another answer as well as one comment to this answer. One remark there was that it carries a religious connotation. I agree, but in the form of *Computerguru* I’d see the aspect of a knowledgeable person *and* teacher to be predominant. But it’s arguably a subjective matter.

---

As for **Streber**. It doesn’t fit at all. However, I can see how you ended up with this word. The traits of a person that qualifies as a geek/nerd often coincide with those of a *Streber*. And I’d hold that *Geek* and *Nerd* when used in German can hold an equally pejorative meaning, depending on the context.

It is also a misconception to assume that technology geek = geek. In that sense one might consider the “eingedeutschte” *Geek* a false friend (as German English teachers call it), as the German use of the word is almost exclusively attached to people with special interests in ***technology***. In English you can easily have science geeks etc. Not to mention “hybrid” forms in people of various interests.

Comment: Spezi/Spezl for me is exclusively a friend - I would not ever have thought of specialist. Learning something new every day :) guess it is regional...

Comment: I don’t think _Freak_ is normally negative (in German).

Comment: Spezi ist m.W. ein weit gebräuchliches Wort für Freund in Süddeutschland/Österreich. Als Spezialist hätte ich das nie gelesen. Neben Freak war auch Guru lange gebräuchlich. Freak ist m.E. seit den späten 60ern für Drogennehmer, abgedrehte und überdrehte Typen gebräuchlich, nicht notwendig abwertend und auch gebräuchlich als Selbstbezeichnung (Freak-Brothers). Ein Streber ist m.E. autoritätshörig, gefallsüchtig, angepasst und opportunistisch. Der Geek dagegen ist leidenschaftlich an seinem Stoff interessiert und bekommt zwar auch gute/beste Noten, aber aus anderen Motiven als d. Streber.

Comment: Nur weil es in Süddeutschland in der Form gebräuchlich ist, wird es nicht überall in der Form verwendet. Mir ist der süddeutsche Gebrauch zwar auch geläufig, aber eben auch der oben beschriebene. Guru finde ich auch ein gutes Beispiel welches ich vergaß.

Comment: Bzgl. Streber ... autoritätshörig? Warum? Das wird von denen die die Bezeichnung verteilen vielleicht so gesehen und ist auch als Konnotation beabsichtigt, aber ich sehe es nicht als enthalten. Ich meine Du verwechselst Streber und Schleimer ;) In manchen Kreisen wird ein IQ oberhalb 110 ja schon abschätzig bewertet und mit Strebertum in Verbindung gebracht. Was ich aber aussagen wollte ist, daß der Geek ob seiner Leidenschaft oft als Streber gilt und in entsprechenden Kreisen auch so verachtet wird.

Comment: What do you mean the this pronunciation thing of nerd?

Comment: @inf: okay, take the English word *knuckle*, right? The *k* in it is silent. Now take the word *drunk* and reverse it, yielding *knurd*. Attempt to pronounce that already as you normally would in English. Since the *k* is silent again you'd end up with the pronunciation that you also find in the differently spelled *nerd*. Hope that helps. It's just one theory how the word came about. Kind of playing with the stereotype that *nerds* are the ones abstaining from parties and therefore not being drunk "ever".

Comment: Ah interesting, didn't know that. Thought you were referring to something in German.

Comment: This should not be community wiki: http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: @Martin-マーチン: undo it if you can. I don't care about the rep, that's all.

Comment: Did I miss a/the clear-cut translation of "Non techies giving a negative moniker to computer-techies".  In the sense of "these nerds/dweebs know computers but maybe not how to tie their own schuhe".  It may also be that this stereotype were typically American.

Answer (score 14):

A neutral term would be *ITler* or, more German, *EDVler,* which is very broad. If people spend a lot of time with computers, they’re often called *Computerfreak* – I, however, don’t know whether it is still current. I know it from C64 times, when it was something special to have a computer.

Comment: Could be just my perception, but isn't EDVler getting an endangered species, supplanted by the ITler?

Comment: @Stephie You forgot to mention that the ITler species meanwhile evolved into the IMCler species… *Irgendwass Mit Computer*. :)

Answer (score 10):

The word *Streber* is typically found in a school context and describes a person that is not very well loved and that spends a lot of time learning, with a primary goal of pleasing the teachers.

A *Geek*, *Computerfreak*, *ITler*, or sometimes *Nerd* is a person interested in the matter (or at least spending a lot of time with it, which typically correlates), but the word does not imply that the person is not much loved.
It does often imply that the speaker finds the person described as such a bit strange, though, especially when the words used are *Geek* or *Nerd*.

Comment: I knew "Computerfreak" long before "Geek" or "Nerd".

Comment: A *Streber* is not necessarily someone who spends a lot of time learning. They called me "Streber" when I went to school, but I did spend very little time in learning, and in many subjects (like english, history, geography, but also sports) I always had very bad grades. But I was best of class in mathematics, physics and chemistry (as said before: without learning at home). I was just interested in those subjects, and therefore I sometimes even knew more then the teachers, and this was why they called me a »Streber«.

Answer (score 9):

If the person holds a degree in computer science or a related field I would go with "**Informatiker**".
If you have a personal/close relation to the person you can go with "**Nerd**" which is usually not offensive just like "**Geek**" (However people might not know what a Geek is, since this word is not popular in Germany). 
If you are in a professional enviroment I would go with the role/job description of that person. Say thinks like "**Entwickler**"(developer), "**Admin**"(administrator) and "**Integrator**" (system integrator).
If the person does not work in this field but does programming for fun you could use "**Programmierer**" or even "**Hobbyprogrammierer**" (to point out that he is doing it for fun/in his free time and not for a living)
If you want to describe someone without knowing his specialisation or don't want to point it out I would go with one of these:

- **(Computer) Experte**
- **(Computer) Spezialist**
- **(Computer) Guru**

(I would use them in that order. "Guru" has a somewhat religious meaning)

I would not suggest using "EDVler". Everyone who uses some office applications for work could be described as EDVler. ITler is a bit closer to what you are trying to say but just states that the person is somewhat related to "Informationstechnologie" in general and does not provide any information about his expertise or activities.

Comment: more than a religious meaning I'd associate the teacher aspect with *Guru*. I also don't see any difference in meaning (albeit in awkwardness when using them) of the terms ITler and EDVler. Otherwise an excellent answer and +1.

Comment: The parenthesized *Computer* could also be replaced by *EDV* .

Answer (score 7):

The common word for “geek” is „Geek”. An “IT guy” could be an „IT-Mensch“.

Comment: IT-Mensch? Wirklich?

Comment: @userunknown: actually it's true. You hear *IT-Mensch* often from people who have no connection to the topic and lack the understanding to be more specific. It's their way of being specific without exposing themselves to ridicule when using terms they don't understand. I have heard this term several times.

Comment: It is of course meant to be colloquial as in „unser IT-Mensch“.

Answer (score 3):

**Progger** wenn die Person wirklich programmiert. Kann eventuell norddeutsch sein.

Answer (score 3):

I’d suggest „Technik Checker“ / „Computer Checker“ / „PC Checker“ to describe someone who spends a huge amount of their time “doing computer things”, or whose friends believe is good at technical things (electronic, not mechanical). This would mainly be used among male youths. It does not sound pejorative to me.

Comment: I like your mention of Checker. Although it is not standard German, it is never used with a negative connotation .

Answer (score 1):

In Austria and Bavaria they say IT Mokel for a IT guy.

Comment: I'm from Austria and work in IT but I never heard IT Mokel. Any specific region in Austria?

Comment: I heard it from people from Vienna

Comment: You gotta love those Austrian terms. I for one cherish all the German dialects. It's one of the beauties of our (sometimes not so common) language.

Comment: @SteffenTimm - Oh, very interesting.

Comment: I live in the greater Vienna area, and have never heard it before. At the very least, it's not a common term.

Comment: Never heard it from Bavaria either. I consider it a non-standard term. As such -1.

Answer (score 1):

**ITler**: Umgangssprachlich für Personen, die in der IT Branche arbeiten.
(Colloquial language: for the people who work in the IT sector.)

Comment: Aussprache auf Englisch?

Answer (score -3):

What about "Fachidiot"? Maybe a little pejorative?

Comment: A little? Do you think?

Comment: Fachidiot ist auch nicht auf IT / Computer beschränkt.