# German word for "Keyuser" or "Power User"

Tags: english-to-german

I am looking for a true German word for a Computer user with "extra permissions and education".  Any suggestions?

Comment: Soweit ich beobachte, ist *Poweruser* durchaus üblich im Deutschen.

Comment: Bei mir im Geschäft heissen Keyuser Keyuser. Sie auch [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-User) dazu. Aber im Detail ist die Frage nicht beantwortbar solange unklar ist, was ein Keyuser eigentlich sein soll.

Comment: I have been working for nearly 30 years in IT now, and have never heard of _keyusers_ or (rather!) _key users_ before. A quick Google search suggests that this term is specific to [SAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_SE).

Comment: The German Wikipedia has entries for both [Key-User](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-User) and [Power-User](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-User), and no equivalent "true" German term is suggested there.

Comment: @WalterTross I work with a SAP-system ;)

Comment: Kann es sein dass *Key-User* eigentlich ein Scheinanglizismus ist?  Oder von SAP und so in Deutschland erfunden wurde?

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking of a situation where what I understand by "power user" is linked to the user having "extra permissions". Can you elaborate a bit on your definition of the terms, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both expressions are common expressions in German, but at least for me the have different meanings:

A **key user** is a special trained user. The user is not part of the IT-team, but a user and (s)he is a connection between users and IT-team. See also [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-User).

A **power user** is an experienced user who knows the program very good and uses much more features as the standard user (these guys makes the life of key users difficult, because they ask questions the key user can't answer and must be forwarded to the IT-team). There is a big chance that power users become the next generation key user.

In my business key users are called **key users** (it is an understandable foreign word). Key users also teach the normal users and in this function they are also called **Multiplikatoren** (ok, also not a pure German word, but the origin is not English).

Answer (score 3):

The official Microsoft language portal for translation their products says, that the right translation for *Power user* is *Hauptbenutzer* (main user in free translation)

You can search the IT terms on your own [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=power%20user&langID=de-de).

Comment: It sounds awkward to me to translate user as Benutzer. I’d rather use Nutzer (or Anwender) instead.

Comment: Duden dictionary rates the frequency of the both words as equal. In my German operating system I met actually only "Benutzer" form.

Comment: I recommend against this translation. Not because I'd find "Benutzer" awkward in any way, but rather because I'd intuitively associate "Hauptbenutzer" with something like "the largest group of users". Depending on the software (and to the disadvantage of actual power users, because it means they are an irrelevant niche group whose needs have a low priority), this can be a decidedly different user profile than that of a power user.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who works in IT, you could say *Systemadministrator* or *Nutzer mit erweiterten Rechten* (in contrast to a user with a guest account or with standard permissions).

For someone who likes to tinker with computers at home and has some knowledge, being it related to hardware or software, you could take a look at the answers to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24448/how-do-you-say-geek-it-guy-in-german).

Comment: Unter Windows gibt es (oder gab es) einen "Hauptbenutzer", keine Ahnung, ob das was damit zu tun hat. Das etwas saloppere *Admin* kenne ich - vorwiegend aus der gesprochenen Sprache - ebenso *Sysop*.

Comment: Key User sind aber nicht unbedingt Systemadministrotoren.

Comment: @knut Das Problem ist, dass aus der Frage nicht klar hervorgeht, was eigentlich gemeint ist. „Key user“ und „power user” sind für mich auch zwei völlig verschiedene Dinge. edit: oh, habe deine Antwort gerade gelesen.

Comment: @Philipp Meine Antwort enstand auch erst als mir ein deutscher Begriff für einen Sonderfall einfiel. Im Fragetext hat der OP ja auch etwas definiert was er meint.

Comment: Auf SE gibt es noch den Superuser. Dessen Definition scheint mir auch nicht klar umrissen. "Intensivnutzer" wäre mir vom sonstigen Sprachgebrauch eingefallen, aber gebräuchlich ist das nicht.